# Carousel component from bootstrap-vue3 not working

Tags: carousel, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I am creating Vue app with vue3 and using the bootstrap-vue3 package for Frontend.
I followed [Bootstrap-Vue docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/carousel) and copied the following code but Carousel doesn't work.
Of course, I can use another package for Carousel, but almost works already was done with this package. So I am looking for a solution to use this package.
Kindly let me know please if you folks how to fix this issue.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-1"
      v-model="slide"
      :interval="4000"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      img-width="1024"
      img-height="480"
      style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
      <!-- Text slides with image -->
      <b-carousel-slide
        caption="First slide"
        text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum."
        img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=52"
      ></b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with custom text -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=54">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with image only -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=58"></b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with img slot -->
      <!-- Note the classes .d-block and .img-fluid to prevent browser default image alignment -->
      <b-carousel-slide>
        <template #img>
          <img
            class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
            width="1024"
            height="480"
            src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=55"
            alt="image slot"
          >
        </template>
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slide with blank fluid image to maintain slide aspect ratio -->
      <b-carousel-slide caption="Blank Image" img-blank img-alt="Blank image">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eros felis, tincidunt
          a tincidunt eget, convallis vel est. Ut pellentesque ut lacus vel interdum.
        </p>
      </b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>

    <p class="mt-4">
      Slide #: {{ slide }}<br>
      Sliding: {{ sliding }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        slide: 0,
        sliding: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSlideStart(slide) {
        this.sliding = true
      },
      onSlideEnd(slide) {
        this.sliding = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I couldn't find the carousel feature in the bootrap-vue3 library https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/components/ Or am I missing something? Be aware that your linked bootstrap carousel is for vue 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
There is a BCrousel component in [cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/src/components/].[1]


  [1]: https://github.com/cdmoro/bootstrap-vue-3/tree/main/src/components

Comment: @fairdev9610 the BCarousel component is here: https://github.com/cdmoro/bootstrap-vue-3/tree/main/src/components/BCarousel, but you didn't specify what "isn't working", so I don't know what issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `active` prop in any one of the `b-carousel-slide` tag to display the slide.

It is something not mentioned in the documentation.